# Group by to count occurrences of unique ID/itemName across multiple CSV files and sum up value in another column using pandas/python

Tags: python, pandas

I'm currently trying to do the following:

1. Check the number of time "id"/"itemName" occur across different csv files in mypath (al files are formatted the same [see below *sampleCSVFile*], id and name is unique in every file, but may repeat or not in other files)
2. Sum value for the "Entries" column for a given id/itemName across all the files.
3. Get the highest/lowest number in "Entries" column across all the files for a given id/itemName

sampleCSVFile in my mypath:

```
id    itemName    NonImportantEntries    Entries    SomeOtherEntries
1      item1              27              111             163
2      item2              16               22              98
```

My Code so far:

```
import pandas as pd

from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join

#readMyDirectoryForFiles
mypath= <myDirectoryPath>
   
list_of_files = [f for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath, f))]

#GenerateAllFilesInDirList
list_of_files = [mypath+x for x in list_of_files]

#LoadAllFilesToPandasDFs
dataframes = [pd.read_csv(fi) for fi in list_of_files]

#count id/itemName Occurences Across All Files and sum up value in column "entries", but also check for highest/lowest value in column "entries" and record it for the output file -> this step is really hard for me.

#tried the below but received -> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'groupby' , also not sure where to start and how proceed with capturing highest/lowest number for "entries" across all the files.
count_occurences = dataframes.groupby(['id', 'itemName']).sum()['entries']



...
#save file in the following format
df.to_csv('finalFile.csv', index = False)
```

Expected finalFile.csv format:

```
    id  itemName    noOfOccurencessInFiles  TotalEntriesFromAllFiles    HighestEntriesNumber    LowestEntriesNumber
    1     item1            11                       3500                       1200                      0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with the parameter `as_index=False` for columns from `id, itemName`:

```
final = pd.concat(dataframes).groupby(['id', 'itemName'],
    as_index=False)['entries'].sum()

fnal.to_csv('finalFile.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Hi @jezrael, thank you this helps a lot. With the above I was able to get sum for "Entries" for unique ID across all the files. But how could I add to this a way to count how many times a unique file ID/itemName occurs across all my files? For example Id 1  occurred 10 times across 11 files. I would like to add the count result as a column 'noOfOccurencessInFiles' many thanks in advance!